# How to set Metadata header in gRPC call when using Camel?

Tags: apache-camel, grpc, grpc-java

I'd like to pass custom Metadata header to gRPC call. Header has to be derived from additional data that's not present in the raw gRPC request.
Something like this works all right without Camel:

```java
ValidateService validator = newBlockingStub(channel);
Metadata header = new Metadata();
header.put(Metadata.Key.of("CustomAuthorization", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER), generateToken(restRequest));

ValidationRequest request = mapToGrpcRequest(restRequest);

ValidationResponse response = validator
        .withInterceptors(MetadataUtils.newAttachHeadersInterceptor(header))
        .processValidation(request);
```

But I'd like to leverage Camel and was hoping for this to work:

```java
from("direct:validationInput")
        .process(exchange -> { // an attempt to attach metadata header derived from Exchange
            String token = generateToken(exchange.getIn().getBody());
            exchange.getIn().setHeader("CustomAuthorization", token);
        })
        .process(this::mapToGrpcRequest)
        .to("grpc://localhost:8088/example.proto.ValidateService?method=processValidation&synchronous=true");
```

It doesn't work because Exchange header is not propagated to gRPC Metadata.

Is there any other way? I wasn't able to figure it out from https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/grpc-component.html.

I was thinking about using `.addInterceptStrategy()` and registering `ClientInterceptor` via `CamelContext` but not sure this proper.

**EDIT**
Now I'm thinking that passing custom `CallCredentials` would be perfect.
Crafted in Java it'd be:

```java
ValidationResponse response = validator
    .withCallCredentials(...)
    .processValidation(request);
```

but I see no way to do it in Camel